# Is there any possibility of using MetroUI in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, microsoft-metro

I want to Change the normal Look and feel of C# winform by Using MetroUI ..is there any possibility of doing this

Comment: Can i do this without 3rd party DLL ..

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use my MetroFramework for .NET winforms applications!
http://viperneo.github.io/winforms-modernui/

Comment: Was about to post this as an answer. Good work!

Comment: this link may help you http://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/#GettingStarted

Comment: @viperneo Link is down

Answer (score 2):

Try this, its example of Metro UI on winforms:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138661/Metro-UI-Zune-like-Interface-form

http://www.pfgrid.com/Metro_UI_Tiles_WinForms.aspx

http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=1160

http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/metro-ui-controls.aspx

Comment: Nice links. It seems simpler to just get VS 2012 and learn to code Metro-style apps (or whatever they're called now...) But +1 for good options.

Comment: Can i do this without 3rd party DLL ..